# How to create new model with foreignkey in django

Tags: python, django

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ScheduleDefinition(models.Model):
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    config = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
```

These are my models.  I am trying to create a new `ScheduleDefinition`(The `Schedule` already exists and I know the ID I want to use for my foreign_key).  I have a predefined Schedule id that I want to use, but it is not working..

Posting this body:

```
{
    "schedule_id": 1,
    "config": {
        "CCC": "ccc"
    }
}
```

Error I get:
`null value in column "schedule_id" violates not-null constraint`

What am I doing wrong? When I create new `ScheduleDefinition` models, the `Schedule` model will already be created previously.  I am never going to be creating new `Schedule`'s when I create new `ScheduleDefinition`'s.

Serializer:

```
class ScheduleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class ScheduleDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    schedule = ScheduleSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ScheduleDefinition
        fields = ['schedule', 'config']
```

View:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Schedule, ScheduleDefinition
from .serializers import ScheduleSerializer, ScheduleDefinitionSerializer


class ScheduleList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScheduleSerializer


class ScheduleDefinitionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ScheduleDefinition.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScheduleDefinitionSerializer


class ScheduleDefinitionDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ScheduleDefinition.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScheduleDefinitionSerializer
```

View error:

```
File "/app/server/schedules/serializers.py", line 13, in ScheduleDefinitionSerializer
   schedule_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="schedule")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 247, in __init__
  super().__init__(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 108, in __init__
    'Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, '
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.
```

Comment: Can you share the serializer (and view) you are using?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have read-only set to true, because the `ScheduleDefinition` model will never be creating a new `Schedule` model.

Comment: I think you need to specify `fields = ['schedule_id', 'config']`

Comment: Failing with the same issue. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @asojidaiod you have to change post data to repeat serializer structure  `{"config": {"CCC": "ccc"}, "schedule": {"id": 1, "name": "some name"}}`. or write another serializer

Comment: @ncopiy I passed in the entire proper schedule object as you described and I get the same error.

Comment: @ncopiy I even doing a get on a scheduledef,  copying the created object, and passing that into a post and get the same error.

Comment: @ncopiy I can create objects fine through the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified Schedule as required (not null), but you aren't actually posting any information to it. Currently your serializer is expecting information in the form:

```
{
    "schedule": {
        "name": "Foo" 
    },
    "config": {...}
}
```

`schedule_id` is being discarded when you post. Furthermore, you've specified that `schedule` is a *read only field*, meaning even if you posted a schedule, it would still be discarded.

If you'd like to post to foreign keys, you'll either need to specially handle it by manually writing the create/update logic for a [writable nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) (which can be a bit of a hassle), or use a different (writable) foreignkey field serializer and serialize your other read-only data another way.

For example, the following setup should work (untested) with the data you're currently trying to POST:

```py
class ScheduleDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    schedule = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Schedule.objects.all()
    )
    schedule_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="schedule.name")

    class Meta:
        model = ScheduleDefinition
        fields = ['schedule', 'schedule_name', 'config']
```

With this your post should work, and you'll still have read-only access to the corresponding schedule's name via the `schedule_name` field in your list/detail views.

---

### EDIT

My earlier version of the code would not have been compatible with the original desired POST data. The following should work without altering the POST

```py
class ScheduleDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    schedule = ScheduleSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    schedule_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source="schedule",
        queryset=Schedule.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ScheduleDefinition
        fields = ['schedule', 'schedule_id', 'config']
```

Comment: Getting same error as above with your approach, passing in ```{
        "schedule_id": 1,
        "config": {
            "BBB": "bbb"
        }
}``` as my post data.

Comment: My `Schedule` model is pre-populated with data.  It should never be added to, edited, or deleted from.  It's just different Schedule types (monthly, daily, weekly, etc..) which is why I have it as read-only.  Basically I just need to figure out how I can post a specific schedule type to a new ScheduleDefinition I am creating.

Comment: remove the _id in your POST data:

`
{
    "schedule": 1, "config": {...}
}
`

Note that in the example code I've told the serializer that we're changing the "schedule" field to only be a primarykeyrelated field

Comment: Did exactly as you put, getting the same error `null value in column "schedule_id" violates not-null constraint`.

Comment: Though I had to add `schedule = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)` or I get an error on my view

Comment: What error do you currently get with the suggestion in the Edit?

Comment: Same error as before.  `schedule_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="schedule", read_only=True)` but I did have to change to this.

Comment: What error are you getting when you leave out read_only=True?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216020/discussion-between-cosine-nomine-and-asojidaiod).